# I cannot figure out how to make a specific array from strings, integers, or variables

Tags: arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

These are my errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Student.<init>(Student.java:22)
at Roster.<init>(Roster.java:35)
at Roster.main(Roster.java:15))
```

I understand that the issue is because I have an array of 3 grades (the last 3 in the string of student names) that are not being stored correctly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Roster 
{ 
    static String[] students = {"1,John,Smith,John1989@gmail.com,20,88,79,59", 
                                "2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,91,72,85",
                                "3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,85,84,87",
                                "4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,91,98,82",
                                "5,Michael,Brauer,mbrauer@wgu.edu,30,99,98,96"};

    static ArrayList<Student> myStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new Roster(); 
    } 

    public Roster() 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) 
        { 
            String y = students[i];
            String[] variable = y.split(",");

            String id = variable[0];
            String first = variable[1];
            String last = variable[2];
            String email = variable[3];            
            int age = Integer.parseInt(variable[4]);
            int grade1 = Integer.parseInt(variable[5]);
            int grade2 = Integer.parseInt(variable[6]);
            int grade3 = Integer.parseInt(variable[7]);
            int[] grades = new int[]{grade1, grade2, grade3};

            //Here is the first issue that I am having: Nothing stores to grades.

            Student x = new Student(id, first, last, email, age, grades);

            myStudents.add(x); 
        }

        print_all();

        print_invalid_emails(); 
        for (Student y : myStudents)
        {
            print_average_grade(y.getId());
        } 
    } 

    public static void print_all()
    {
        for (Student x : myStudents) 
        { 
            System.out.println(x);  
        }
    }

    public static void print_invalid_emails()
    {
        for (Student x : myStudents)
        {
            String email = x.getEmail(); 
            if (!email.contains("@"))
            {
                System.out.println("INVALID EMAIL: " + email);
            }
            else if (!email.contains("."))
            {
                System.out.println("INVALID EMAIL: " + email);
            } 
            else if((email.contains(" "))) 
            {
                System.out.println("INVALID EMAIL: " + email);
            }
        }

        remove("3");
        remove("3");
    }

    public static void remove(String id) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < myStudents.size(); i++) 
        { 
            if (myStudents.get(i).getId().equals(id)) 
            { 
                myStudents.remove(i);
                System.out.println("STUDENT ID: (" + id + ")  *NOT FOUND*");
                return;
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("STUDENT ID: (" + id + ")  !DELETED!");
    }

    public static void print_average_grade(String id)
    {
        for (Student y : myStudents)
        {
            if(y.getId().equals(id)) 
            {
                double total = 100;
                double average = total / 3;
                System.out.println("STUDENT ID: (" + id + ")  " + average);
            }
        }
    } 
}

public class Student 
{ 
    String id;  
    String first;
    String last;
    String email;   
    int age;
    int[] grades;

    public Student(String id, String first, String last, String email, int age, int[] grades) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    //This is the other problem. I am trying to make an array

    public int[] gradeArray = {grades[1], grades[2], grades[3]};

    public String getFirst() 
    {
        return first; 
    } 
    public void setFirst(String first) 
    { 
        this.first = first; 
    } 
    public String getLast() 
    {
        return last;
    } 
    public void setLast(String last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    } 
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    } 
    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }  
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    } 
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age=age;
    } 
    public String getId() 
    { 
        return id; 
    } 
    public void setId(String id) 
    { 
        this.id = id; 
    }
    public int[] getGradeArray()
    {
        return gradeArray;
    }
    public void myGrades(int[] grades)
    {
        this.grades = grades;
    }   
    //Print to output
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "STUDENT: ID-" + id + "  AGE-" + age + "  NAME-" + last + ", " +  first; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you're storing three grades into a (0-based) int array:

```
int[] grades = new int[]{grade1, grade2, grade3};
```

But then you're trying to access grades[3] which is beyond the bounds of the array.

```
public int[] gradeArray = {grades[1], grades[2], grades[3]};
```

Also worth noting: Erickson_1990@gmailcom will fail your valid email test.  Not sure if that was intentional for testing reasons, or just a typo.